# Are there any limitations in BackgroundTask Framework?

Tags: ios, background, ios13, background-task

I looked for any limitations of the new BackgroundTask Framework of iOS 13 but never found an explicit answer neither in the Apple Documents nor online. For example in Background Fetch Mode the background execution of the app is controlled by the system so this feature could not be used for important updates; [Performing Finite-Length Tasks API](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-008) on the other hand prevents your app being suspended when moved to background for a maximum 3 minutes.

With BackgroundTask could i call a function indefinite times and perform if for how long i want? Do i have to wait between the calls of two Background Tasks?

Comment: Background tasks are identified. You can only have one instance of a task with a given identifier running at a time. Background tasks have much the same limitations of background fetch; you have a couple of minutes to complete your task. If you use excessive memory or CPU your app can be terminated. The main difference is you can specify an earliest execution date rather than an execution interval to suggest when your task should run. iOS still determines whether or not to run your task at a given time.

Comment: I’d suggest watching WWDC 2019 [Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707). If these are processing tasks, you can submit multiple ones (e.g. one for background fetch, additional/multiple processing tasks, etc.). If you could clarify the nature of the background tasks you’re talking about (i.e. functionally, what are they doing), we can probably offer more concrete counsel.